# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundObjectResult' to MyDto

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have controller's method which return mapped Dto. In case I find nothing in my Db (null) I want to return NotFound(), else I want to return Ok(item). But IDE shows me error (like in title). Code below:

````
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ArticleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IArticleRepository _repository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public ArticleController(IArticleRepository articleRepository,IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = articleRepository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

// GET: api/Article/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public async Task<ArticleReadDto> Get(int id)
        {
            var item =   await _repository.GetArticle(id);
            if(item == null)
            {
                return NotFound(item);
            }
            var mapped_item = _mapper.Map<ArticleReadDto>(item);
            return  Ok(item);
        }```
````

Comment: Your action method is expecting you to return a `ArticleReadDto`, not a `NotFoundObjectResult`.  If you want to be able to return those type, make your method return an `IActionResult` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public async Task<ArticleReadDto>
```

to:

```
async Task<IActonResult<ArticleReadDto>>
```

and

```
var mapped_item = _mapper.Map<ArticleReadDto>(item);
 return  Ok(item);
```

To

```
var mapped_item = _mapper.Map<ArticleReadDto>(item);
return  Ok(mapped_item );
```

and

```
return NotFound(item);
```

to

```
return NotFound();

//or

return NotFound( new ArticleReadDto());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are calling the methods `Ok` and `NotFound` that are fulfilled by the `ControllerBase` class.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The methods that you are using return an `ActionResult`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok

If you wish to return these statuses then having a `IActionResult` return type might be more appropriate:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var item =   await _repository.GetArticle(id);
    if(item == null)
    {
        return NotFound(item);
    }
    var mapped_item = _mapper.Map<ArticleReadDto>(item);
    return  Ok(item);
}
```